# Including a html form in a php script

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a PHP script which has a HTML form included within it. Please help me edit this:

```
$SoapClient = new SoapClient ( NULL, $options );
try {
    $cities = $SoapClient->getCities ();
    // echo var_dump($SoapClient->getCities ());

    echo "<form action= " . "'$" . "PHP_SELF' method = 'post'>";
    echo "<h4>Choose Origin</h4>";

    foreach ( $cities as $city ) {
        echo "<input type='radio'    name = 'origin' value = " . $city . "> <br>";
    }

    echo "<h4>Choose Destination</h4>";

    foreach ( $cities as $city ) {
        echo "<input type='radio'    name = 'destination' value = " . $city . "> <br>";
    }
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submitButton' value='Calculate Great Circle'>";
    // show soap request and response
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "<h3>SOAP error</h3><pre>" . $e . "</pre>";
    echo "<h3>SOAP error last response</h3><pre>" . $SoapClient->__getLastResponse () . "</pre>";
    echo "<h3>SOAP error last request</h3><pre>" . $SoapClient->__getLastRequest () . "</pre>";
}
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: why would we help you ? do you got an error ? what is your problem ?

Comment: when i try to run this script, the value for city is not displayed. I only see the radio button, no value.

Comment: `$cities = $SoapClient->getCities ();` should be `$cities = $SoapClient->getCities();` (no space)

Comment: Also don't forget to close your `<form>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display the cities names next to your radios, try this in your two loops :

```
foreach ( $cities as $city ) {
    echo "<label><input type='radio' name='origin' value='" . $city . "'>" . $city . "</label> <br>";
}
```

And also replace

```
echo "<form action= " . "'$" . "PHP_SELF' method = 'post'>";
```

by

```
echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">';
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue of displaying the names of the city but does not solve the next issue which arises when i click the submit button. i get this bug: 
    Not Found

The requested URL /FirstMultiTierApplication/ThePresentationLayer/$PHP_SELF was not found on this server.'

Comment: replace echo "<form action= " . "'$" . "PHP_SELF' method = 'post'>"; by echo "<form action= '" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "' method = 'post'>";

Comment: action is set to self by default? why to set it up?